# ISO dateTime formatting in Java 7

Tags: java

I have date format like this `2016-11-25T12:29:10.588+01:00`

I want to convert this to `milliseconds` and later while printing I have to again convert `milliseconds` to `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"` this format.

I have tried this its working fine but it give wrong value when time between `12` to `13`, **It sets hours to 00 insted of 12 or 13**

`(yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+-ZONE)`, for example: `2006-06-13T15:58:00.123+01:00`.

```
SimpleDateFormat ISODateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
Date result = ISODateFormat.parse(matcher.group(0));
syslogTimeStampInMillis = result.getTime();
```

Comment: You're using `hh` instead of `HH`. As always, read the `SimpleDateFormat` docs *very carefully*, checking every aspect of the format, when something doesn't behave as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

- hh = 12hours format, in combination with AM/PM
- HH = 24hours format

(And to consider is - for other cases, like month names - the `Locale.getDefault()` that is used under the hood. One could specify the Locale too.)